# undefined index at sending POST data

Tags: php, html, mysql

I got some problems and it looks like I can't find any way to work around it. I tried use isset for each POST data, but while it would solve all the problems, the data won't be added.
I'll leave you the HTML code and PHP, so maybe you will be able to help me debugging this code.

> adm_prod.php (the html page which handles the form)

```
            <form method="POST" action="includes/prod-add.php">
  Product Name<br>
  <input type="text" name="Name"><br>
  Price:<br>
  <input type="number" name="Price"><br>
            Product Description<br>
            <input type="text" name="Description"><br>
            Photo<br>
            <input type="file" name="Photo"><br>
            </br>
            <button name="submit">Add Product</button>

</form>
```

> prod-add.php (php file which handles the inserting/validating info)

```
<?php
include 'databaseConnection.php';

$name = $_POST['Name'];
$price = $_POST['Price'];
$description = $_POST['Description'];
$target_dir = "images-uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['Photo']['name']);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES['Photo']['tmp_name']);
    if($check !== false) {
        $uploadOk = 1;
    }      else {
        echo "The File Is not an image";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

if(file_exists($target_file)) {
    $filename = $_FILES['Photo']['name'];
    $extension = end(explode(".",$filename));
    $name = rand(pow(10, 7), pow(10, 8)-1);
    $newfilename = $name . "." .$extension;
    $uploadOk = 1;
    echo "Image already exists. Image Name changed to " . $newfilename;
}
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg") {
$uploadOk = 0;    
echo "Sorry, only JPG, PNG and JPEG are accepted";
}



if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo " Sorry, your product was not added, please check the error";
    $fileupload = 0;

} else {
    if (move_upload_file($_FILES['Photo']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
        $fileupload = 1;
        $imagePath = basename( $_FILES['Photo']['name']) . "." . $imageFIleType;
        }
}

if($fileupload == 1) {

    $addProd = "INSERT INTO meniu (name, price, description, path) VALUES ('$name','$price','$description','$imagePath')";


    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    if ($conn->query($addProd) == TRUE) { ?>
<script>
    window.alert("Product: <?php echo $name; ?> has been added successfully ");
    </script>


    <?php    } else { ?>
        <script> 
            window.alert("Error: <?php echo $conn->error; ?>");
        </script>
  <?php  }

}

?>
```

I'm sorry if the code is not very clear, I'm still learning PHP. Usually I don't have any problem like this, but it's the first time I'm using image upload.
Basically, in the database I wanna introduce Name, Description, Price, Photo Path. The path should be something like ../uploads/photoname.extension .
Thanks for help.

Comment: What is the error again?

Comment: sorry, forgot to link the error. Here it is: http://vvcap.com/E5eeEQAlvEO

Comment: **WARNING**: Using manual escaping is extremely error prone and a single mistake can lead to a crippling [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: You need to check all the `$_POST` variables using a combination of `if` conditions and the `empty()` function. Otherwise your code is assuming that there is a value when in fact there isn't. That is why you are getting the error, because some field might not have a value upon submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused when the form is submitted without filling all the fields first. So, you need to check if the `$_POST` variables are set by firstly checking if the form has been submitted.

Also, add this to your `form` tag in the **html** `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

```
$name=$price=$description="";
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST") {
//if the form has been submitted, initialize the values.

$name = $_POST['Name'];
$price = $_POST['Price'];
$description = $_POST['Description'];
$target_dir = "images-uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['Photo']['name']);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
:
//rest of the code
:
}
```

Inside that check if the file was uploaded with it:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_FILES['Photo'])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES['Photo']['tmp_name']);  
}
```

Encapsulate the entire process inside the `if` statement.

Also, as told by tadman, use parameterized queries using **Prepared Statements** or **PDO** in your mysql queries.

Comment: still getting undefined index Photo and Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty

Comment: @CojocariCristian I updated my answer, check it now.

Comment: http://vvcap.com/EDOitICgbWT another set of errors, also I updated from move_upload_file() to move_uploaded_file() as the second one is the correct syntax. The reason why I used it is to check if the file was uploaded successfully and if yes, start inserting data.

Comment: @CojocariCristian it maybe because you don't have the permissions to move the file in that location. Try chmod 777 on the folder (google how to do that if you don't know) and also check if the php.ini has safe mode activated. Google will easily give you solutions. As for this question, i think your matter has been solved.

Comment: Im using wamp to test my script. I tried a lot of things right now, and after all the "debugging" I did, I found out that somehow, all the problem is within the move_uploaded_file() function. Basically, it can't upload the photo from tmp folder to the original folder. Also, I tried instead of uploading, to show up the tmp file within a <img> and still not working. I have no ideea why I can't upload that file.